# Looping through session array to create shopping cart

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am adding the id of my product to a session array when the add to cart button is clicked. How to I set up my query to loop through all of the id values in my array. At the moment I have just added my session variable into the query but obviously this isn't going to work.

Code:

```
  $_SESSION['cart'] = array();

  array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['theid']);


  $query = "Select * From Products WHERE ProdID = '$_SESSION['cart']'";
```

Comment: `implode(',', $_SESSION['cart'])` -> `where PredID IN (1,2,3)`

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you need to use an `IN` operator in your SQL query :

```
`SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProdID IN (1,2,42, etc ...)`
```

As you can push IDs in your array and your query will always work.

Then use implode func to get your array as a single string to format in your sql query : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.implode.php

```
      $str =  implode(',', $_SESSION['cart']) ;
      $query = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProdID = '$str'" ;
```

Comment: funny how you just copied my comment as a code. This way it will not work of course. EDIT: thanks for the edit now. Better. Still not working.

Comment: YES just because you did not explained it as well as he could understand ! ;)

Comment: fair enough. But then you should make it right. It's not yet.

Comment: Ok let's do it mate !

Comment: @MounirOnGithub Thanks makes sense haven't used the implode function before, am getting an error which I will look into

Comment: @yellowranger it should be: `$query = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProdID IN ( $str ) " ;`

Comment: @MounirOnGithub Working fine now was an error else where in my code :)

Comment: Good job :D @yellowranger